# how much should be spent on each to optimize output?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If x is the number of thousands of dollars spent on labour, and y is the thousands of dollars spent on parts, then the output of a factory is given by:

$Q(x, y)  =  42x^{1/4}y^{3/4}$

Where Q is the output in millions of units of product.

Now, if $153,000 is to be spent on parts and labour, how much should be spent on each to optimize output?

Round your answers to the nearest dollar.

with this question, I know that

$Q(x, y)  =  42x^{1/4}y^{3/4}$ & $x+y=153000$

and y= labour and x= parts

I know that the Qx = $\frac{3}{4}x^{-3/4}y^{3/4}$ & $\frac{39}{4}x^{1/4}y^{-1/4}$ and that the Gx= 1 and Gy=1

But how do I get the final answer after this steps?